# Reciever has no segue with identifier swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I am trying to pass value from Realm via segue to another viewcontroller. The problem is it is crashing with error : Reciever has no segue with identifier. I tried other way, prepareforsegue but it is not working as well as this one.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let lektire = datasource[indexPath.row]
    let destinationVC = DetaljiViewController()
    destinationVC.programVar = lektire.ime
    destinationVC.performSegueWithIdentifier("oLektiri", sender: self)
}
```

However, my segue is definitely there, and its identifier is properly set (see screen shot below).

[image: Here is the screenshot of segue]

What is going on, and how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the other segue that you have in your storyboard!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for you have to call performSegueWithIdentifier from the view controller you are currently inside of and either make the sender the indexPath or you can make it your datasource item.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
   self.performSegueWithIdentifier("oLektiri", sender: indexPath)

   // Another WAY
   self.performSegueWithIdentifier("oLektiri", sender: datasource[indexPath.row])
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "oLektiri") {
       let indexPath = sender as! NSIndexPath
       let toViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? NextViewController
       let lektire = datasource[indexPath.row]
       toViewController?.selectedObject = lektire
    }

    // Another WAY
    if(segue.identifier == "oLektiri") {
       let lektire = sender as? lektireTYPE
       let toViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? NextViewController
       toViewController?.selectedObject = lektire
    }
}

// An example of what the next view controller should look like
class NextViewController: UIViewController {
    var selectedObject: ObjectType?
}
```

Comment: It gives error -> Cannot assign value of type 'PrikaziLektire' to type String? It gave me the this error with every way I tried to work it out

Comment: Can i see code possibly this a type mismatch meaning that you are trying to set a variable that is a String? to a object that is PrikaziLektire which is not possible

Comment: First viewcontroller http://paste.ofcode.org/ZCChbc4ydTsSLRTHGhedp2 
Second http://paste.ofcode.org/sCTFrkFBxjFWgCaRqm8sC5

Comment: So in your second link var selectedObject: String? should be var selectedObject: PrikaziLektire?

Comment: Still 'Receiver has no segue with identifier

Comment: I would check inside storyboard to make sure there isn't like an extra space at the end of the identifier. If possible show the error again

Comment: Don't set kind to "custom" in storyboard unless you have a custom class so just change that and should work

Comment: No problem :] Good luck with your project